# How to change Layout and hide content on window.print()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a web application where the vendor can print the invoice. so for print i am using windows.print() in print preview it shows as screen shot of the current page. but the vendor has some standard printed paper with his details and some blank space i want to print only text on the sheet and i don't want any style or tables to be printed.

How to do this is it with media quires or any other way

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest fix would be to have a print css file / query:

```
@media print {
   .styledContent {
        display:none;
    }

}
/*Also reset the styles of the other elements*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media print` in order to override the classes according to your requirement.
Use it on the same css class or you can use it in a separate css file.